# How do I store email addresses input in a textbox to viewModels string array?

Tags: c#, wpf, email, mvvm

I have one view `LinkWindow` here I have a textbox to enter the email address by comma separated value, after this I have one more textBox for email body and at the bottom I have one Send Button. I want this to be implemented in a viewModel.

Like if I user type `abcd@test.com,degf@gmail.com,test@gmail.com,test@yahoo.com`  then these values should be stored in a viewmodel's string array. Although the email id validation I want to do in view at runtime after putting the comma. Can anybody please suggest how do I do this?

I can write code

```
private string _name
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set 
    { 
        _name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

and in XAML bind the textbox's text property to "Name", but that will only bind the one email id. Suggestions please

Comment: You need to use a ValueConverter which converts from your comma separated string to a string array and back http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: But then how do I validate the Email address in view, if it's format is proper email address or not?

Comment: You can validate the email address array in the viewmodel by using a CustomValidationAttribute using IDataErrorInfo http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/creating-custom-validation-attribute-for-data-annotation/

Answer (score 2):

@ChristianPaulin has already given you some good tips... you could indeed convert a comma separated `string` into a collection of `string`s using an instance of the [`IValueConverter` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See this linked page for details on how to implement it.

While I can't actually test this at the moment, I think that you should be able to implement your `Convert` method something like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value.IsNull() || value.GetType() != typeof(string) || targetType != typeof(ObservableCollection<string>)) return null;
    string emailAddresses = (string)value;
    string[] addresses = emailAddresses.Split(new string[1] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    ObservableCollection<string> addressCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    foreach (string address in addresses) addressCollection.Add(address.Trim());
    return addressCollection;
}
```

To clarify, this should take an input `string` in the form

> `abcd@test.com,degf@gmail.com,test@gmail.com,test@yahoo.com`

and return an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

You could use it to bind from an `ObservableCollection<string>` property in your view model (let's say named `EmailAddresses`) to a `TextBox.Text` property in the UI like this (don't forget to define your `YourConvertersPrefix` XAML Namespace Prefix):

In `UserControl` or `Window` `Resources`:

```
<YourConvertersPrefix:StringToStringsConverter x:Key="StringToStringsConverter" />
```

In `UserControl` or `Window`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding EmailAddresses, 
    Converter={StaticResource StringToStringsConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Your solution is fine, but it seems that it does not work. in my UserControl I added resources and added converter with key value. Again for the textBox `Text="{Binding EmailAddress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource stringsToArrayOfStringsConverter}}"` I added, but the converter does not hit

Comment: Firstly, let's be clear... my solution *does* work. If you have implemented it incorrectly, that's a different matter. Did you rename the `Converter` to `stringsToArrayOfStringsConverter` in the `Resources` section too? It's impossible for me to guess what you've done wrong... check the linked page above to see how you should set up your `Converter`. Also, judging by the name of your `Converter`, you shouldn't use a `string[]`...use an `ObservableCollection<string>` like I told you.